# What exactly did Jesus say in Matthew 16:28?

Tags: matthew, luke, mark

Matthew 16:

> 27 For the Son of Man is going to come with his angels in the glory of his Father, and then he will repay each person according to what he has done.

Jesus was talking about his second coming on the last day.

> 28 Truly, I say to you, there are some standing here who will not taste death until they **see the Son of Man coming in his kingdom**.”

But they alll died without witnessing his second coming. Was Jesus talking about his 2nd coming in verse 28?

Maybe not.

There is a parallel account in Mark 9:

> 1 he said to them, “Truly, I say to you, there are some standing here who will not taste death until they **see the kingdom of God after it has come with power**.”

Mark was talking about the kingdom of God and not about the person of Jesus.

There is another parallel account in Luke 9:

> 27 But I tell you truly, there are some standing here who will not taste death until they **see the kingdom of God**.”

Luke's account was even less specific than Marks'.

There are basically two wordings here: Matthew's and Mark's. Which wording is more likely to be what Jesus had actually said on this single occasion?

Comment: reminds me my question: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/79220/what-is-the-reason-for-not-experiencing-death

Comment: See also  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/111/until-they-see-the-kingdom-of-god-in-luke-927-and-parallels

Comment: In Matt 16, Jesus is definitely discussing His second coming in V27 but V28 is discussing the establishment of that Kingdom by Christ which necessarily precedes the coming of Jesus will all His angels in the glory of the Father (we now know by more than 2000 years).

Comment: @Tony Chan It’s possible that Jesus used the reference “taste death” as a representative word for the second death as in: (Revelation 2:11, 20:6, 20:14, 21:8).  The Revelation after all says: “The Revelation of Jesus Christ, which God gave Him to show His servants—things which must shortly take place.” (Revelation 1:1).  So in that sense there is no separate theology of Jesus from the gospels to Revelation.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I appended the OP.

Comment: I believe this is duplicated several times on BH : the best and most comprehensive _answer_ (I would say) is [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/114/21426).